# Simple way to flip rectangle position on the stage

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a simple way to take existing rectangle on the stage and "flip" the rectangle so that if it was on the left it's now on the right side?

Comment: I see you switched the question title. So you're looking for simple `DisplayObject` help instead of `BitmapData` help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is quite simple by manipulating the rectangle's x position.

```
rectangle.x = stage.stageWidth - rectangle.x - retangle.width;
```

is about as simple as you can get. It may not be what you're looking for because I have no idea what you're trying to do, but that's how you go about simple position manipulations using variables like the stageWidth.

Answer (score 0):

This should mirror it horizontally:

```
rectangle.width = -rectangle.width;
```

Comment: `rectangle.scaleX = -1` is also used in this case.